# How do I find the last tag involving a specific path but before a specific commit?

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a script that generates a changelog, i.e. a list of commits. I want to feed it a tag—or any reference for that matter—and it should:

1. From the given reference, look back in time and find the first tagged commit, i.e. the latest tag before it.
2. Print out a list of commits between these references.

One last thing though, since I'm working with a monorepo containing many subprojects, it also needs to take into consideration a given path, i.e. filter out commits not involving that path.

So I know I can get a list of commits between references `a` and `b` involving `path` with:

```sh
git log --oneline a..b -- path
```

My ending reference, `b`, is fed into the script, but I still have to figure out my starting reference, `a`, and that's where I'm stuck.

I know of `git rev-list --tags --no-walk -- path` to list only tagged commits for a given path, but if I also pass a commit reference—to get only commits up to that reference, it doesn't get what I expected, instead it simply includes the passed reference in the result, but still brings newer tags.

Assuming git can do it on its own, could someone point me in the right direction? It doesn't need to be super robust and it could assume some guidelines were followed regarding tagging commits and whatnot, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a question to clarify, why do you use `--no-walk` here? (I mean, since you seem to want a list)

Comment: @RomainValeri That's for an intermediate step when I'm trying to find out the beginning of the commit range that will give me the list.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that and add more information about what I have already figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found something, though it relies on a particular of my case.

So due to it being a monorepo, all my tags are prefixed with the subproject to which it refers. This prefix also coincides with the path of the subproject. e.g. Let's assume a subproject lives in `cool-project/super-app`, so all tags related to it are prefixed with `cool-project/super-app`.

Also, downgrading my changelog script to only accept full formed tags, like `cool-project/super-app/v2`, I can now assume that:

1. The previous tag also starts with `cool-project/super-app`.
2. The changes I'm interested in logging happened inside the `cool-project/super-app` directory.

Giving this state I found that we can use `git describe` to find the **previous tag**:

```sh
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match "prefix/*" "tag^"
```

Where `prefix` is the deconstruct of my tag (version part removed), and `tag` is the argument fed into the script.

Finally I can produce the list of commits between the two tags relating to `super-app` with:

```sh
git log previous-tag..tag -- prefix
```

Where `previous-tag` is the output of the last command above, and once again `tag` is the argument fed into the script and `prefix` is the deconstruct of that argument (version part removed).

If anyone got suggestions or remarks about this solution, please do let me know. Thank you.